# Laravel mysql multiple where query

Tags: mysql, laravel, where-clause

I have the following

```
return DB::table('recipe_symbols')
   ->where('symbol_id', 8)
   ->get(['recipe_id']);
```

it works just fine. Now I have the following to return a more filtered result

```
return DB::table('recipe_symbols')
   ->where('symbol_id', 8)
   ->where('symbol_id', 16)
   ->get(['recipe_id']);
```

I get no results, even though the rows with symbol_id 8 and 16 exists. I tried with raw query and still the same issue.

What is going wrong? What I want to achieve is get recipes by `symbol_id` based on what symbols the user is selecting.

I tried `whereIn()` but that brings back recipes that have a certain `symbol_id` but don't have the other. For example it brings 2 recipes, from which one has a `symbol_id` of 8 only and second has both 8 and 16. I need to get all the recipes that have `symbol_id` = 8 and 16, nothing else.

EDIT***
Database structure

```
recipe_symbols_table
----------------------
|id | recipe_id | symbol_id |
-----------------------------
|1  | 2         | 8
|2  | 2         | 16
|3  | 3         | 8
|4  | 3         | 16
|5  | 4         | 8
|6  | 4         | 30
|7  | 5         | 8
|8  | 5         | 28    
|9  | 6         | 8
|10 | 6         | 31
|11 | 7         | 8
|12 | 7         | 18
```

EDIT***

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM sie_hp_cookbook_recipes_symbols WHERE symbol_id=8 and symbol_id=16';
$qry = DB::select($sql);
```

Comment: I need to return only the first 2 results

Comment: Could you add the raw query you ran to the question?

Comment: @cjds I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following gives me the first two results (2 and 3). Hope this helps!

```
SELECT a.`recipe_id`
FROM `recipe_symbols_table` a
    INNER JOIN `recipe_symbols_table` b
        ON a.`recipe_id` = b.`recipe_id`
WHERE b.`symbol_id` IN (8,16)
GROUP BY a.`recipe_id`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.`symbol_id`) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want all `recipe_id` where certain symbols are present.

---

### This is hard in MySQL

This is not going to be trivial in MySQL. Because MySQL parses row by row just doing an `AND` will return nothing. One row can't have a `symbol_id` of 8 and 16.

So we need to compare two tables with the same rows. This is usually done with a `JOIN` and an intersect. But MySQL doesn't support intersect.
(Hence problems.)

---

### How to solve it

Using a combination of `UNION` and `GROUP BY` we can simulate an interssection but I have no idea how to do it with Eloquent.

Thus your best bet is a `raw_query`. The raw MySQL query for this will be

```
SELECT recipe_id from (
 (SELECT * FROM sie_hp_cookbook_recipes_symbols WHERE symbol_id=8)
 UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM sie_hp_cookbook_recipes_symbols WHERE symbol_id=16)
) AS t1 GROUP BY recipe_id HAVING count(*) >= 2;
```

Link to an example fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4150/15/0

---

Now a Laravel solution

```
$first= DB::table('recipe_symbols')
                           ->where('symbol_id', 8);
return DB::table('recipe_symbols')->where('symbol_id', 16)
                           ->unionAll($first)
                           ->groupBy('recipe_id')
                           ->having('count(*)>2')
                           ->select(['recipe_id'])
                           ->get();
```

Complicated, eh!

Comment: Your solution is working, not completely but is working. On top of that simple query I have to join the recipes table which I did but on some different symbol_id selection is bringing some results that it shouldn't, I guess that's for another topic. Should I accept? (in my opinion it makes clear why my first approach wouldn't work, so I believe yes?)

Comment: You could accept and post another question if you feel it is sufficiently different. Why don't you come in on chat and we'll try to solve the other problem if it is different

Comment: the accepted answer is the right solution, without union, it works perfectly and thank you

Answer (score 0):

raw query

```
SELECT a.recipe_id FROM (
  (select * from recype_symbols where symbol_id = 8) a 
  join (select * from recype_symbols where symbol_id = 16) b 
  on 
  a.recipe_id = b.recipe_id)
```

I'm not sure if this is correctly in laravel way

```
 DB::table('recype_symbols')
            ->join(DB::raw('(select *  from recype_symbols where symbol_id = 16 or symbol_id = 8) as b'),'recype_symbols.recipe_id','=','b.recipe_id')
                ->where('recype_symbols.symbol_id',8)
                ->where('b.symbol_id',16)
                ->select(['recype_symbols.recipe_id'])
                ->get();
```

Comment: same results like whereIn(), it return the recipes that have a symbol_id 8 but not 16 and the ones that meet the where clause

Comment: I've seen your edit, I get the same results, it's driving me nuts

Comment: it does, it's insane can't figure it out why

Comment: If you query  db   DB::table('recipe_symbols')->where('symbol_id', 16)->select(['recipe_id'])->get();    Is result 16

Comment: yes it does, I just double checked everything. I have 5 recipes, 2 of them whom have a symbol_id = 8, 16, 27. I have another 3 that have symbol_id = 8, 30. I need to return the first 2. If I use whereIn() or orWhere() I get all of them because they all have symbol_id = 8

Comment: DB::table('recipe_symbols')->select(DB::raw('select symbol_id from recipe_symbols where symbol_id = 8 or symbol_id=16'))

Comment: no, it returns empty, if I remove one where it returns but obviously wrong :(